# MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, php, apache-2.4, database, ubuntu-18.04

MySQL is running on Ubuntu 18.04. We have many databases running on this single server and many sites running from those databases.

All sites working fine except one site. That site frequently goes down (2 times a day). Apache is running when the site goes down but after restarting apache its back to working. After checking apache logs, I found this error message

> 

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2033 
[Thu Dec 05 08:23:37.373621 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 13008]  PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in
> /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2033
```

We have also enabled logic monitor web checks on that site. We receive mail about the site's unavailable when site goes down.

Is this error related to Apache server, DB server or in some code?

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I think this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35145690/2412335

Comment: Thanks but if you are saying about 
$this->query("set session wait_timeout=600"); this value, it's already set to the same value. Is there any change required?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, 600 is already quite high, but maybe you could try an even higher value?

Comment: The message is ambiguous.  Which happened? (1) The client timed out and was disconnected, or (2) The mysql server crashed.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.